# Bootstrap-Datepicker: Set Min or Max dates and disable days that are out of range

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-datepicker

I have the following two DatePickers that I am using in my `ASP.Net` WebForm. I want to disable the dates from the second DatePicker that are in the past than the date selected in the first DatePicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $("#FromDate").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        orientation: 'bottom'
    });
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $("#ToDate").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        orientation: 'bottom'
    });
});
</script>
```

And the .aspx code is:

```
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        From Date: 
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="auto-style1">  
        <div class="form-group">  
        <%--<label for="usr">FromDate:</label> --%>                     
            <div class='input-group date' id='FromDate'>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFromDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%--<label for="usr">ToDate:</label>--%>
            <div class="input-group date" id="ToDate">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxToDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What to do?

Comment: The gist of it will be to set the selected date from datepicker one as the minDate/startDate for datepicker 2.

Comment: Thanks Rohan for your answer. I got that. But I wasn't sure how to do that in the code. I am not sure how to access the selected date from the first DatePicker. Later in the code, I am setting the selected date from the first DatePicker in a TextBox. But that is much later in the code and I have written that in C#.

Comment: Im not too familiar with this exact component but i see from the docs (i presume) `.on('changeDate', function(e) { console.log(e);})` will give you access to the change event of each picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually suggest that you try and find a component that will do this for you.

For example: I'd try and find one that can apply CSS styles & disable etc. as part of its exposed feature set... as I know for a fact I've used one in the past where you an supply a `maxDate` and the component (internally) will enable and disable days|months|years as needed.(This was it: [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex1))

But if you want to go at it another way... you can emulate the logic as I've stated in my comment, and at the very least least reject / allow based on min/max events...

> The idea is on each calendars hook into the `onClick`/`onChange`, or in your case `changeDate` event and
>   prevent the click if the date is past or before what your current min or max
>   would be.

Please see this really <strike>untidy</strike> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yLkz8nL/2/) and code sample below:

```
var allowedMin, allowedMax = 0;

var from = $("#FromDate").datepicker(opts)
  .on('changeDate', function(e) { 
    // set new min
    allowedMin = new Date(e.date);    

    // if we have no max yet, or one has been set
    if(!allowedMax || new Date(e.date) < allowedMax) { 
        // if we're in the allowed range update
        $('#from').html(e.date);
        $('#status').html('update allowed');
        return true;
    } else {    
        // ... otherwise reject
        $('#FromDate').datepicker('update', new Date($('#from').html()));
        $('#status').html('update prevented/reverted');
        return false;
    }
  });

var to = $("#ToDate").datepicker(opts)
  .on('changeDate', function(e) {
    allowedMax = new Date(e.date);    
    if(!allowedMin || new Date(e.date) > allowedMin) { 
        $('#to').html(e.date);
        $('#status').html('update allowed');
        return true;
    } else {
       $('#ToDate').datepicker('update', new Date($('#to').html()));
       $('#status').html('update prevented/reverted');
       return false;
    }
  });
```

**Update:**

I see bootstrap-datepicker will allow you to set an array of [disabled dates](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled), thus the new logic would be (on the respective changeDates), feed any dates prior to your min/max into that collection.